# How to solve VertexAI prediction endpoint error?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to get predictions from an endpoint that is already created in VertexAI through UI.

I am getting an error when I run the following code

```
from typing import Dict
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = '../golden-tempest-xxxxx.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path, scopes=[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"], )


aiplatform.init(
    project='golden-tempest-xxxxx',
    location='us-central1',
    credentials=credentials,
)

def predict_tabular_classification_sample(
    project: str,
    endpoint_id: str,
    instance_dict: Dict,
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
):
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    client = aiplatform.gapic.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    instance = json_format.ParseDict(instance_dict, Value())
    instances = [instance]
    parameters_dict = {}
    parameters = json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())
    endpoint = client.endpoint_path(
        project=project, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id
    )
    response = client.predict(
        endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters
    )
    print("response")
    print(" deployed_model_id:", response.deployed_model_id)
    # See gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/predict/prediction/tabular_classification_1.0.0.yaml for the format of the predictions.
    predictions = response.predictions
    for prediction in predictions:
        print(" prediction:", dict(prediction))


df = pd.read_csv('../btc_test_classification_2.csv')

df_dict = df.to_dict('index')

predict_tabular_classification_sample(
    project="xxxxx",
    endpoint_id="886215168080478208",
    location="us-central1",
    instance_dict={'instances': [df_dict[4]]}
)
```

**Error**:

```
InvalidArgument: 400 {"error": "Column prefix: . Error: Missing struct property: tick_count."}
```

My training data contains the same columns I have in test. [image: columns]

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Looks like this might be related to  schema property, you can add this in your code and try:
`column_names = ['column_name_1','column_name_2',...etc]
df = pd.read_csv('../btc_test_classification_2.csv', names=column_names)`
Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried code for endpoint provided here. https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/index.html. Here I gave list of dictionaries for instances in the predict endpoint and it worked.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so that it will help other community members in their research work.